# Genarate DRM server certificate

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, drm, huawei-developers, android-drm

I'm following instruction Wiseplay DRM in main page:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Media-Guides/config-cert-0000001168721058

And I stuck in step 4. Upload the certificate

I have download p10 file from the previous step. And I don't know how to genarate issued DRM server certificate, level-2 CA certificate.

The document say:

```
Submit the CSR file to the certificate management organization to purchase the DRM server certificate and have it issued.
```

But I don't understand how to genarate it with public key (.p10 file)

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step is not necessary. If you have bought licence from Huanyu Trust (Beijing) Technology Co., Ltd., you can upload it to Huawei server for hosting.

But it is suggested to use the DRM server certificate applied by WisePlay DRM to provide services for your business.

Then you can skip this step.

Comment: Thank for the comment. I have skip this step but I have another problem that I can't run demo app on real device in Cloud Debugging. Have you ever test on it ?

Comment: It is not suggested to test Wiseplay service in CloudDebug.

The function is controlled.

You ip is not in allowlist, so the connection is refused.

You can test in local phone and share us the public IP address of your phone.

You can share it here or create ticket in this address:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback/#/

After adding to allowlist, you will be able to connect to Huawei server.

Comment: Yeah that is a problem when I can't find any device is in list support device but anyway thank for your support

Comment: So that mean every device using Wiseplay DRM have to send their IP to able to add to allowlist. I think that will be a problem when deploy app using Wiseplay DRM

Comment: @NightRider, This is only for test. In actual scenarios, the Content Provider server is connected. Therefore, you do not need to apply for allowlist on Huawei.

Comment: @shirley So if I want test with "Content Provider server". How can I connect to it. I have register account on Huawei developer

Comment: @shirley I have PortalID, AES Key, Sign Key but no clue how to use it

Comment: @NightRider, you could follow [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Media-Guides/wiseplay-resources-0000001057749543?ha_source=hms1)

Comment: @shirley Seem that url: https://drmkit.hwcloudtest.cn:8080/drmproxy/v3/getLicense not working. And url: https://wiseplay.cloud.huawei.com/drmproxy/v3/getLicense return error 1408 with message "Can not find aesKey for portalId" when using portalID: TestForDeveloper